# Option to disable Hive Compression in Insert Overwrite

Tags: hive

I want to do a insert overwrite to hdfs folder as csv /textfile.
    In hite-site.xml, `hive.exec.compress.output` is set to `true`.
    I cannot do a `set hive.exec.compress.output=false` as the code is being executed in a custom build framework.
    Is there an option to turn off hive compression like an attribute of the insert overwrite statement?

Comment: Could you explain a little more about how your query is getting executed?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify properties in `hite-site.xml`, one option would be from the hive `CLI` or `beeline`, but it would be only for the current session, if you close the session and the next day start a new session you will have to do the same.

As an example:

Log in `hive CLI` or `beeline`

```sh
$ hive

to see the value of the property:

hive> SET hive.execution.engine;

to overwrite its value for the current session

hive> SET hive.execution.engine=tez

or in your case 

hive> SET hive.exec.compress.output;
hive> SET hive.exec.compress.output=false
```

Other commands that can be useful from the Linux shell are:

```sh
$ hive -e "SET" > hive_properties

to write a file with all hive properties, or 

$ hive -e "SET;" | grep compress

to see a group of hive properties from the console
```